# Confusion about proof involving sums and binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation

In the below proof, how is the second line derived from the first?

The first term in the second line has n replaced by (n+1),  I cant see why, specially, because this change is not made in the second term.

I understand the rest of the proof but not this part.

What is the manipulation that is being performed?

---

[image]

Comment: It's just a shift in the index.

Comment: I sometimes find it helpful to rewrite the $\Sigma$s as the first few terms followed by ...

Comment: @user296602 Why is this shift only required in the first term?  Why don't we replace $n$ in the second term by $(n+1)$  like in the first term?

Comment: @Loli: The second summation has a factor of $n$. Including an $n=0$ term doesn't affect its value.

Comment: @Loli As always with sums like this: Write out the first three or four terms of everything, and compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reindexing of the sum. The general form is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1} x^{n} \tag{1}
$$
by a change of variable "$n\leadsto n+1$" *(are you comfortable with this?)*.

To see how it is applied here:

- First sum: 
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \underbrace{n\binom{\alpha}{n}}_{a_n} x^{n-1} = 
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \underbrace{(n+1)\binom{\alpha}{n+1}}_{a_{n+1}} x^{n}\,.
  $$

However, in the second sum this is not used. Instead, what is used is simply that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\binom{\alpha}{n} x^{n} = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\binom{\alpha}{n} x^{n} + \underbrace{0\cdot \binom{\alpha}{0} x^{0}}_{=0}
= 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\binom{\alpha}{n}x^{n}\,,
$$
i.e., that adding the term "$a_0 x^0$" to the sum does not change the value here, as $a_0=0$.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.  So without any reindexing, the first sum would also involved  $n$  and not $n+1$?  just like in the second sum?

Comment: @Loli Yes, but then you'd have $x^{n-1}$, which you don't want. The idea here is to have $x^n$ in both sums, to be able to add the power series easily.

Comment: Clever, merci !

Comment: @Loli De rien !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we set $n=N+1$. Since $n$ starts at $n=1$, $N$ starts at $N=0$, and we have
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}n\binom\alpha nx^{n-1}=\sum_{N\ge 0}(N+1)\binom\alpha {N+1}x^{N}.$$
Then set $N=n$, as they're dummy variables.